# Searching script in Python

Tags: python, search

im trying to make a script which search some file in whole computer similar to Search in windows. I want to do it without any libraries.

I started with setting dir to begginng of disk and then checking how much dirs i have - i want to make a function that will search for new dirs in current dir so at the end ill have list of all dirs in disk. But when i try to found all files ending with ".txt", i get error message WindowsError5 Acces Denied. What am i doing wrong? Thanks

```
import os

os.chdir("\\.")
dir = os.listdir()

dirs = []

for x in dir:
    if os.path.isdir(x):
        dirs.append(x)

for y in dirs:
    o = os.listdir(y)
    for p in o:
        if p.endswith(".txt"):
            print(p)
input()
```

Answer (score 2):

First, if you want to walk a directory tree, use [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) instead of trying to build it yourself. And if you're trying to learn how something like os.walk works, the source code should be right there in os.py.

Second, you probably don't have access to your entire filesystem unless you run as Administrator, so you're going to get a bunch of Access Denied errors as you try to step through the directories you don't have access to. You have to use try/catch to deal with these errors in whatever way you find appropriate (e.g., print the error and move on to the next directory)

Third, this whole idea is probably misguided. Windows Desktop Search does not actually search your whole tree, it keeps a database and searches that, which is much faster (and also allows users to search into paths they couldn't reach directly—for example, you might have access to /Users/foo, but not to /Users, which means WDS can show you files in /Users/foo but your script cannot).

Fourth, this whole thing is much easier to do with the POSIX 'find' tool or… I forget the name, but there's a DOS-derived tool that also comes with Windows that does the same thing but not as flexibly. Either way, it's a one-liner shell/batch command instead of dozens of lines of Python.

Finally, the way you've written this, it's going to search the current drive, not all drives, which probably isn't what you want, is it?

Answer (score 1):

You've hit a directory that you don't have permission to look in. So what. Catch the exception and continue the search.